# Saml2RequestException: Assertion has expired. Assertion valid NotOnOrAfter

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-4, saml-2.0

i am using  the https://stubidp.sustainsys.com

This form will send a SAML2 Response to a service provider. If the In Response To ID field is empty, the Response is considered unsolicited (IDP initiated).

Incoming AuthnRequest 
`<saml2p:AuthnRequest xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" ID="_8f325c15-801a-4404-b456-ec4537570311" Version="2.0" IssueInstant="2020-05-23T06:32:39.6960629Z" Destination="https://stubidp.sustainsys.com/b13a3cfa-d358-441f-a46a-c79f3cc7cc72/">
  <saml2:Issuer>https://localhost:44391/</saml2:Issuer>
</saml2p:AuthnRequest>`

Saml2RequestException: Assertion has expired. Assertion valid NotOnOrAfter 05/23/2020 06:38:02 +00:00.

Please provide the Solution